# My code for NIM game. Error in computer's turn code

Tags: python, loops

```
#Question 1
def playNovice(marbles):
    import random
    rand = random.randint(1,(0.5*marbles))
    print('Computer takes: ', rand)

#Question 2
def userPlay(marbles):
    userAmount = marbles
    while userAmount > (marbles * 0.5):
        userAmount = int(input("Input Number of Marbles you want to take from pile: "))
    return userAmount

#Question 4
import random
marbles = random.randint(10,100)
print("Size of Marble Pile: ", marbles)
OneOrZero = random.randint(0,1)
starter = int(input("Enter a Number between 0 and 1 to decide who starts: "))
while marbles > 1:
    if starter == OneOrZero:
        while marbles > 1:
            print("Your Turn!")
            rand = userPlay(marbles)
            marbles = (marbles - rand)
            print(marbles, 'Marbles Remaining')
            print("Computers Turn!")
            rand = playNovice(marbles)
            marbles = (marbles - rand)
            print(marbles, 'Marbles Remaining')          
    elif starter != OneOrZero:
        while marbles > 1:
            print("Computers Turn!")
            rand = playNovice(marbles)
            marbles = (marbles - rand)
            print(marbles, 'Marbles Remaining')
            print("Your Turn!")
            rand = userPlay(marbles)
            marbles = (marbles - rand)
            print(marbles, 'Marbles Remaining')
```

An error occurs after the computer has taken its marbles. Alot of the time i find it hard to understand what the error code means, or at least how to fix it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ruairimangan-cliff/Documents/Work:Personal/Engineering Foundation/Semester 2/Foundations of Computer Programming/NIM/Coursework Assignment (NIM) 2.py", line 44, in <module>
    playNovice(marbles)
  File "/Users/ruairimangan-cliff/Documents/Work:Personal/Engineering Foundation/Semester 2/Foundations of Computer Programming/NIM/Coursework Assignment (NIM) 2.py", line 23, in playNovice
    rand = random.randint(1,(0.5*marbles))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/random.py", line 213, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/random.py", line 186, in randrange
    raise ValueError("non-integer stop for randrange()")
ValueError: non-integer stop for randrange()
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, `random.randint()` only takes **int**s (integers).

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randint(1, 10)
6
>>> random.randint(1, 10)
2
```

However,if you use a **float**, it gives you the same error:

```
>>> random.randint(1, 10.5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 240, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 196, in randrange
    raise ValueError, "non-integer stop for randrange()"
ValueError: non-integer stop for randrange()
>>>
```

Here is your updated code

```
import math
#Question 1
def playNovice(marbles):
    import random
    rand = random.randint(1,math.floor(0.5*marbles))
    print('Computer takes: ', rand)

#Question 2
def userPlay(marbles):
    userAmount = marbles
    while userAmount > (marbles * 0.5):
        userAmount = int(input("Input Number of Marbles you want to take from pile: "))
    return userAmount

#Question 4
import random
marbles = random.randint(10,100)
print("Size of Marble Pile: ", marbles)
OneOrZero = random.randint(0,1)
starter = int(input("Enter a Number between 0 and 1 to decide who starts: "))
while marbles > 1:
    if starter == OneOrZero:
        while marbles > 1:
            print("Your Turn!")
            rand = userPlay(marbles)
            marbles = (marbles - rand)
            print(marbles, 'Marbles Remaining')
            print("Computers Turn!")
            rand = playNovice(marbles)
            marbles = (marbles - rand)
            print(marbles, 'Marbles Remaining')          
    elif starter != OneOrZero:
        while marbles > 1:
            print("Computers Turn!")
            rand = playNovice(marbles)
            marbles = (marbles - rand)
            print(marbles, 'Marbles Remaining')
            print("Your Turn!")
            rand = userPlay(marbles)
            marbles = (marbles - rand)
            print(marbles, 'Marbles Remaining')
```

This uses [math.floor](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/math.html#math.floor) to get the bottom integer, so that if `marbles` is 11, we don't want it taking the `randint` of a number higher (6).

Answer (score 1):

The error is visible in the traceback:

```
rand = random.randint(1,(0.5*marbles))
```

The second value of this function call will be a float, rather than an integer. The `randint` function only works with integer arguments. The exception is a little harder to understand than usual though because `randint` is a wrapper around `randrange` where the actual exception is raised.

To fix the issue you need to either force your argument to be an integer with `int`, or perhaps do the calculation in a different way (such as using the `//` floor division operator). Since this looks like a homework assignment, I'll leave the details to you.

You'll probably run into an additional issue though, later, which is that your `playNovice` function doesn't return the number of marbles taken. You may want to fix that one too!